# Django filter find the smallest number group by other column

Tags: python, django

I have a database structure like as below:

```
id     listing     sequence    result

1       1          0           hfdn
2       1          1           hkoq
3       1          2           qaz
4       2          1           bnm
5       3          1           h456
6       3          2           vnm
7       4          0           45hv
8       4          1           1lc0
```

I want to get each group of listing whose sequence is the smallest, the example result is as below:

```
{listing:1, sequence:0}, {listing:2, sequence:1}, {listing:3, sequence:1}, {listing:4, sequence:0}
```

and their matching result.

PS: some sequence is start from 0, some is start from 1, or even more.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-aggregation

Comment: If the answer below helped your above query, can you please accept (upvote) it for the community? :)

Answer (score 4):

you need to group_by `listing` and get minimum `sequence` value. If your model name is `MyModel`, then this should work fine:

```
MyModel.objects.values('listing').annotate(min_sequence=Min('sequence'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, if I want to use this queryset to get one other column in this table , how should I do?

Comment: @YuchenHuang add another line like above but set its results to another variable.

Comment: Like @Jaberwocky said .. or you can do MyModel.objects.all().values('listing').annotate(min_sequence=Min('sequence')) to get all the columns.